# Simple echo client-server in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, client-server

I want to write a echo client-server app using named pipes (I did it with sockets, it worked, but now I want to
do the same with named pipes.) Server has to be multithread.

I thought my programs work when I run them for the first time, it was all good. Every client
connected to server got a message from it.

But now, when I tried to run programs for the second time, I still get this message:

```
mkfifo client2server: File exists
```

(many such messages). This is my output when I tried to run ./echoserver:

```
$ ./echoserver 
Server is working ...
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
mkfifo client2server: File exists
```

how to fix it to work as I want it to? To make a real multithread echo server-client app?

Heres my code:

**echoserver.cpp**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string toString(int d)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << d;
    return ss.str();
}

void* clients_service(void * arg)
{
    int client_id = *((int*)&arg), server2client = -1, buffsize = 255, bytes_read = -1, client2server = -1;
    client_id++;
    char buffer[255];
    string fifoname = "/tmp/server2client";
    fifoname += toString(client_id);

    string fifoclient = "/tmp/client2server";
    fifoclient += toString(client_id);

    if(mkfifo(fifoclient.c_str(), 0666) == -1)
    {
        perror("mkfifo client2server");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    if((client2server = open(fifoclient.c_str(), O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
        perror("open client2server");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(mkfifo(fifoname.c_str(), 0666) == -1)
    {
        perror("mkfifo server2client");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((server2client = open(fifoname.c_str(), O_WRONLY)) == -1)
    {
        perror("open server2client");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;)
{

     if ((bytes_read = read(client2server, buffer, buffsize))== -1)
        {
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (bytes_read == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Connection closed\n");
            break;
        }
        buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

      if (strcmp("\\q",buffer)==0)
      {
         fprintf(stdout, "Server OFF.\n");
         break;
      }

      fprintf(stdout, "From client: %s\n", buffer);
      if ((write(server2client,buffer, strlen(buffer)))== -1)
      {
          perror("write");
          break;
      }

      fprintf(stdout, "Send to client: %s\n", buffer);

      // clean buffer from any data
      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
}

close(client2server);
   close(server2client);

   unlink(fifoname.c_str());
   unlink(fifoclient.c_str());

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int clientsCounter = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "Server is working ...\n");

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, clients_service, (void*)&clientsCounter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compile it like this: `g++ -Wall -pthread echoserver.cpp -o echoserver`

**echoclient.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int client_to_server;
   char *myfifo = "/tmp/client2server";

   int server_to_client;
   char *myfifo2 = "/tmp/server2client";

   char str[255];

   /* write str to the FIFO */
   client_to_server = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
   server_to_client = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);
   while(1)
   {
       printf("\n> ");
   scanf("%s", str);
   write(client_to_server, str, sizeof(str));
   read(server_to_client,str,sizeof(str));
   printf("From server: %s\n",str);
   }

   close(client_to_server);
   close(server_to_client);

   /* remove the FIFO */
   unlink("/tmp/server2client");
   unlink("/tmp/client2server");

   return 0;
}
```

compile it like this: `gcc echoclient.c -o echoclient`

Comment: Don't treat the file already existing as an error.

Comment: The client only uses "unnumbered" fifos. How is this expected to work?

Comment: @alk do you have any idea how to give the same numbers to clients? I have no clue how to make it

Comment: Please see my answer for a possible approach.

Answer (score 1):

To setup multiple connections you need multiple independend instances of a connection. An instance of a connection is represented by a fifo representing itself as a named entry in the file system.

To differentiate between those instances of the connecting channels their identifying names need to be different. In your code they are not. Each cleint uses the same fifos to communicate with server and verse vica.

Change your code to make the fifos' file system entries be named differently for each client.

Think over how it worked using sockets:

- There is **one** listening socket on the server side accepting **all** client connects.
- As the result of accepting a connection **a specific socket** is setup (allowing duplex communication) for **one specific client**).

To replace this using fifos there need to be:

- **one** replacement for the listening socket
- **replacements for each socket** serving each client connection.

Comment: I thought I did it: look at the first seven lines of `clients_service` function in `echoserver.cpp`. I create there different filenames for every client (I add a different number to the fifoname - client_id++ every time I call `clients_service`. If it is wrong, could you give some code sample?

Comment: You are right, I somehow ignored this part of your code. Sry for this. Anyway, what you are trying to achieve when passing the address of a counter to the thread function does not do what you intend, as you do not increment the variable addressed, but a local one. Better increment the counter in the main thread's loop. If incrementing it in the thread function you should protect its access using a mutex. @BrianBrown

Comment: I read your comment, thank you for that, could yuo please see my new code? Im not quite sure if its all good